# Entity framework rollback transaction on exception

Tags: entity-framework

When I encounter an exception in EF I am doing the following...

```
public virtual int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException vex)
    {
        foreach (var error in vex.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            error.Entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        throw;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException uex)
    {
        foreach (var error in uex.Entries)
        {
            error.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is to revert the pending entities that have caused the issue so that further changes can be applied.  This works well.

Now I am making several changes in one go, and I want them all to be reverted if there's an exception.  So I create a transaction, start making changes and, on exception, call Rollback.  The problem is that any changes that were successful before the exception happened remain and are not rolled back.  If I remove the code to set the pending issues to EntityState.Unchanged then the rollback works, but the context is now unusable as there are pending changes that will cause issues on further commits.

Hoping that's explained everything well enough.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> any changes that were successful before the exception happened remain and are not rolled back.

Correct.  When you call SaveChanges() and later roll back the transaction EF and the Database don't agree on the state of your entities.

In this scenario you need to defer calling SaveChanges() until after all your changes are made.  Then the DbContext and Database will always agree on the outcome of your changes.

Comment: Hmmm. Don't really understand this.  I call BeginTransaction(), make my changes and then SaveChanges().  If I get an exception the code above gets called and then I call Rollback().  Don't really see what else I can do.  If I don't set the entities causing the issue to Unchanged then the context is unusable - if I do then the rollback doesn't work.  Actually I have found a solution that seems to work: If I get an exception with an active transaction I now call Rollback() and then dispose and recreate the context, otherwise I run the code above. Seems to work but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Actually, scratch that - it doesn't work.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: What do you mean "if I do then the rollback doesn't work"?  I though the issue was a successful SaveChanges() and a subsequent Rollback, which you just shouldn't do.

Comment: So you are saying that Rollback() should never be called after SaveChanges()?  This isn't something I'm aware of.  My scenario involves performing a complex deletion.

Comment: It shouldn't be as difficult as it is, but it's a legacy app that I've put EF DB first into and we've got to live with what we've got, right?
1. Call BeginTransaction()
2. Update entities - remove relationships, delete children, etc
3. Call SaveChanges()
4. My first few updates work and then an exception is thrown
5. I set the faulted entities to Unchanged so that the context remains usable
6. I also want my entities restored to their original state so I call Rollback()
7. The changes that succeeded are not rolled back.  If I don't set the faulted entities to Unchanged then they are

Comment: It seems that what you're saying is that an EF rollback is not the same as a database rollback?

Comment: Right.  If you have multiple SaveChanges() in a database transaction, your Entity State and Database State will not be consistent on a failure of any but the first SaveChanges().  So don't do that.  Use a single SaveChanges() at the end of your Database Transaction.